# Stringify of JS object adds extra data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have constructed a JS object using the following snippet after getting some great help here on SO:

```
var noticeMap = $('#preExamNoticesTable tbody tr').map(function() {
    var $cells = $(this).children();
    return {
      sequence: $cells.eq(0).children('input').val(),
      noticeUID: $cells.eq(1).text()
    };
});
```

An example resulting noticeMap looks like this (from firebug):

```
jQuery(Object { sequence="1", noticeUID="JP-L23013663997630352308"},
Object { sequence="3", noticeUID="JP-L22913664089460612172"}, 
Object { sequence="4", noticeUID="JP-L22913664090188631530"}, 
Object { sequence="2", noticeUID="JP-L22913664089408651799"})
```

When I try to `JSON.stringify(noticeMap)` it works great apart from that it adds extra data to the string that I do not want to pass on with my POST. It generates numerical keys for each value (object from noticeMap), but after the last desired k:v pair my string also has *context obj*, *length*, and *prevObject* obj. Here is the JSON after I `stringify()` it and POST:

```
{ "0": { "sequence": "1", "noticeUID": "JP-L23013663997630352308" }, "1": { "sequence": "3", "noticeUID": "JP-L22913664089460612172" }, "2": { "sequence": "4", "noticeUID": "JP-L22913664090188631530" }, "3": { "sequence": "2", "noticeUID": "JP-L22913664089408651799" }, "length": 4, "prevObject": { "0": {}, "1": {}, "2": {}, "3": {}, "length": 4, "prevObject": { "0": { "location": {}, "jQuery19105836315711643562": 1 }, "context": { "location": {}, "jQuery19105836315711643562": 1 }, "length": 1 }, "context": { "location": {}, "jQuery19105836315711643562": 1 }, "selector": "#preExamNoticesTable tbody tr" }, "context": { "location": {}, "jQuery19105836315711643562": 1 } }
```

I can not figure out what is causing this to happen. I started to hypothesize it had to do with how stringify handles creating a JSON string from obj of objects, but then I can't use my `noticeMaps()` which is working beautifully now. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need `.get()` at the end of your map function? (Not sure if this applies here, someone call me out if I'm wrong please).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're serializing a jQuery object, so all serializable properties in it are being included in the output. Try this instead:

```
JSON.stringify(noticeMap.get()); // .get will return an array
```

Comment: Thank you very much! On to the next bug

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836459(v=vs.94).aspx

> If value has a toJSON method, the JSON.stringify function uses the
>   return value of that method. If the return value of the toJSON method
>   is undefined, the member is not converted. This enables an object to
>   determine its own JSON representation.

You are stringifying  your object, that is why stringify defining json in it's own way

You need to use `.get()` on your map object to get an array of parameters

`noticeMap.get()`

Comment: Appreciate the reference to the doc, I thought I thoroughly scanned all the docs about stringify, but as you point out I did not well enough!