# transfer selected table's row (javascript DataTables) to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

here is about a javascript widget `DataTables`. An example can be found [here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html).

sorry, i am not a javascript specialist. How can i transfer the selected row (practically my objects from server) back to the server in form of `json-format` ?

i did try to do it with this approach, but it doesn't work:

```js
$('#save_btn').click( function () {
        //table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );
        console.log ( table.rows('.selected').data());
 
 
        var stringData = table.rows('.selected').data().serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajax/storeSelectedContacts',
            data: stringData ,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            success: function (savingStatus) {
               alert("success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("error")
            }
        });
 
    } );
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, its return array of objects.

```
var stringData = table.rows('.selected').data();
```

Second, for convert array to JSON ...

```
var aData = table.rows('.selected').data();
var sData = JSON.stringify(aData)
```

and for send to server you slould indicate that is JSON `dataType: 'json'`

```
$.ajax({
        url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajax/storeSelectedContacts',
        data: sData ,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (savingStatus) {
           alert("success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("error")
        }
    });

} );
```

Comment: Many thanks. 

It practically works, but one issue. If i select one row, the table.data() returns not only my data, but more info: 

`{"0":{"name":"mustermann","surname":"Muster","email":"muster@domain.com","check‌​ed":false},  CONTEXT : [{"oFeatures":{"bAutoWidth":true,"bDeferRender":false, ......... }` . 

Is it possible on client-site to split only my datas without any `context` and so on ?

Comment: to solve this problem you must add `.get()` to array .. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200215/stringify-of-js-object-adds-extra-data